# Unable to create relationship

Tags: sql-server, database

I have the **Orders** table with a `resellerID` column as a Nullable integer. In most of the records `resellerID` is *NULL* while some times it contains an integer associated to the **Resellers** table that contains the `resellerID` and `resellerName` columns.

When I try to add relationship between the two `resellerID` I get the following error:

```
- Unable to create relationship 'FK_Orders_Resellers'.  
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Orders_Resellers". The conflict occurred in database "sales", table "dbo.Resellers", column 'resellerID'.
```

Is the problem the Nullable nature of `Orders.resellerID` column? Is this a bad design choice? What should I do to fix like a pro?

The database was designed by a programmer that left the company and possibly I would like to fix it.

Thanks.

**EDIT:** The error occurs even if the `Orders.resellerID` column contains only *NULL* values.

Comment: Can you verify that for each ResellerID there is an associated ID in the order table?

If there is one ResellerID that doesn't match the Orders ResellerID column then added the constraint will fail.

Comment: Currently the `Orders.resellerID` column contains only _NULL_ values and the error occurs the same.

Comment: Have you seen this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21839309/the-alter-table-statement-conflicted-with-the-foreign-key-constraint

Comment: and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19349055/how-to-set-1-to-0-1-relationship-in-sql-server-management-studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, as always happens, in column data.

Answer (score 0):

The value null in your order table is not available in your reseller table, create a reseller with not assigned in the name, and add this value to your order table and then create the relationship.

Comment: `Resellers.resellerID` is the table Key and it's defined as an integer

Comment: The reserllerid in the order table can't be null if you want to create the relationship. Go to your reseller table create a new record, get the new id and use it to update the orders table with that value, and then create the realtionship

Answer (score 0):

You should create a default value for Resellers, which the Order table should refer to when it has no value for Resellers. Kind of like this:

1. Replace all NULL in orders table with -1. `UPDATE Orders SET resellerID = -1 WHERE resellerID IS NULL`
2. Insert default value into Resellers table. `INSERT INTO Resellers (resellerID, resellerName) VALUES (-1, '');`
3. Apply your FK.
4. Change all code loading `Orders.resellerID` to do `COALESCE(resellerID, -1)` **or** set a default value for the `Orders.resellerID` column

Comment: I suspected about this, is it the most elegant way to solve it? It makes  perfect sense to me to leave it as _NULL_ when there is no associated reseller to the order...

Comment: @Alberto It's hard to say whether this is the most elegant way or not. I prefer this solution.

Comment: I've just discovered that you can create a relationship in this way, check this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25323/allowing-foreign-key-to-be-null

Comment: Yes, I did some further research regarding this and it should be fine to use NULL in a FK column.